# The application manager doesn't find the update

Tags: update-manager, 14.04

I can't find trusty tar. This update seems somewhat half-baked.

Comment: No I'm talking about 14.04 and I'm using the main server.

Comment: And the answer is the same.

Comment: Well, the answer reads "If you're not getting an option to upgrade then your local mirror might be out of date": So is the main server of canonical out of date, or what do you mean?

Comment: @user262849 - what version of ubuntu are you upgrading from?  12.04?

Comment: @fossfreedom: 13.10.

Comment: Which main server are you using? The archive.ubuntu.com servers are still regional, and still take a little time to sync.

Comment: Swiss switch mainserver. Well, they said the update is available since 24 hours ago.. I will try again tomorrow. Good night.

Comment: BTW: archive.ubuntu.com should indeed not should be regional, as the swiss was ch.archive.ubuntu.com. Today I could release it. Thanks.